# How to tell if the result of pick() is a string

Tags: krl

I'm using the [Goodreads API](http://www.goodreads.com/api) through a datasource. I search with the ISBN number, and it returns results if it has any. Here's what it looks like if the book was found:

```
<GoodreadsResponse>
    <Request>
        <authentication>true</authentication>
        <key><![CDATA[--redacted--]]></key>
        <method><![CDATA[api_book_url]]></method>
    </Request>
    <book id="6558055">
        <title><![CDATA[Mythical Man-Month, The: Essays on Software Engineering, Anniversary Edition]]></title>
        <isbn><![CDATA[]]></isbn>
        <link>http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6558055-mythical-man-month-the?utm_medium=api&amp;utm_source=book_link</link>
    </book>
</GoodreadsResponse>
```

If the book wasn't found, it will be the same except that the `<book>` section is absent. You can imagine what the JSON looks like once this XML has been parsed by KRL.

I'm `pick()`ing the `link` tag out of the response like this:

```
url = data.pick("$..link.$t");
```

If there is a `<book>` section, that works just fine; `url` will be a string. But if there was not a `<book>` section, `url` will be an empty array (`[]`).

I only want the actions in my rule to run if `url` is a string. I've tried using things like `if url != [] then` or `url.length()` (which is always zero), but none of those work.

How can I tell when `url` is a string and when it is an empty array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is `.typeof()`, docs [here](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Typeof).

Example condition and action:

```
if url.typeof() eq 'array' then  
  noop()
```

Another way to handle this situation is to pass in `true` as the second argument of pick, which will cause the answer to always be an array. This is described in the docs of [pick](http://docs.kynetx.com/docs/Pick).

Since it will always be an array, you can use `.length()` to test for a match.